# SQL determine if more than one column on a given row has the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that includes 9 columns used to indicated what things to include or exclude in part of the UI. Each column can have the value 'A', 'X', or blank. Each row should have at most 1 'A' in any of the columns.

Due to an error many columns have multiple 'A' values. How can I write a query that returns every row that breaks this constraint?

All I have is something like:

```
SELECT PrimaryKey
FROM Criteria C
WHERE (C.First = 'A' AND C.Second = 'A')
   OR (C.First = 'A' AND C.Third = 'A')
   OR (C.First = 'A' AND C.Fourth = 'A')
   ...
   OR (C.Eighth = 'A' AND C.Ninth = 'A')
```

Is there any cleaner or more elegant way to write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM Criteria C CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_a_s
      FROM (VALUES (First), (Second), . . .  -- list all the columns here
           ) V(x)
      WHERE v.x = 'A'
     ) v
WHERE v.num_a_s >= 2;
```

Note:  Something is probably wrong with your data model if you are storing these values in columns rather than in separate rows.

Comment: I have been hired to fix problems and eventually redesign the database. I will add this to my data model fix-list, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
select 
* from YourTable
where REPLACE(TRIM('X' FROM col1),'A',1)
+ REPLACE(TRIM('X' FROM col2),'A',1)
+ REPLACE(TRIM('X' FROM col3),'A',1)
+ REPLACE(TRIM('X' FROM col4),'A',1)
+ REPLACE(TRIM('X' FROM col5),'A',1)
+ REPLACE(TRIM('X' FROM col6),'A',1)
+ REPLACE(TRIM('X' FROM col7),'A',1)
+ REPLACE(TRIM('X' FROM col8),'A',1)
+ REPLACE(TRIM('X' FROM col9),'A',1)> 1
```

I have used `TRIM` also which requires SQL Server 2017 or above.

or the following:

```
select *
from YourTable
where replace(replace(concat(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9), 'X', ''), 'A', 1) > 1
```

Please see the demo [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1cd35738dacb2fc651d7ac15156f20f7).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this

```
  create table dbo.t1(x int, col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10))


  insert into dbo.t1 values(1,'A','A')
  insert into dbo.t1 values(2,'A','')
  insert into dbo.t1 values(3,'','')
  insert into dbo.t1 values(4,'','X')





  select x
         ,count(case when n='A' then 1 end) as cnt      
    from dbo.t1
cross apply(values ('col1',col1)
                  ,('col2',col2)
                  ---repeat this for columns up to col9...
           )x(m,n)
  group by x
  having count(case when n='A' then 1 end)>1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  LEN(CONCATENATE(C.First, C.... , C.Eighth)) - LEN(REPLACE(CONCATENATE(C.First, C.... , C.Eighth), 'A', '')) = 1
```

As an example

Comment: The OP is trying to find out the records which do not match the criteria of a single A. This query gets you the single A records only

Comment: `CONCATENATE` isn't a T-SQL function.

Comment: CONCATENATE is a TRANSACT SQL and a standard ISO/ANSI SQL function. Read the BOL please ! 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `CONCAT` @SQLpro ... not `CONCATENATE` . **`CONCATENATE`** *isn't* a T-SQL function. That documentation you have cited, and shouted at me to read, tells you that.